# Gradle DSL method not found: 'release()'

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

I just upgraded the Gradle plugin using the AGP Upgrade Assistant in Android Studio to 8.2.0 for a React Native project and I'm now getting this error.

```
Gradle DSL method not found: 'release()'

Possible causes:

Your project may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before and found a solution?

Comment: I too have encountered this issue, but no solution yet

Comment: Still no response/fix to this one.